# Having trouble with Windows Xp + windows 8.1 + ubuntu 14.04lts triple boot

Tags: boot, window, windows-xp

At first I installed Windows Xp from my CD. Then I installed Windows 8.1 from my DVD. Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS. When I turn on my computer I get options to load Windows8.1 and Ubuntu but not XP. What should I do?

Comment: Windows only boots from one NTFS primary partition with the boot flag. So Windows 8 added/overwrote the boot files in your XP install. So grub2's os-prober can only find one set of boot files. If Windows 8 is in a primary partition, move boot flag to it, and use your Windows 8 repair disk to reinstall boot files. You may have to remove the Windows 8 boot files from the XP install and run repairs on it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 automatically sets itself as the default boot up OS so you'll have to change your boot order, turn off fast boot, and change the default OS. You can do all of this from the BIOS menu, which you can access by holding down shift and clicking the Shut Down button from the left menu and then navigating to the UEFI Preferences

Comment: I think it is important to say that he/she could also fully shutdown with cmd `shutdown -s -t 00` running as admin. One can also create a script with that command accessible with one click from desktop. Cheers